# AsyncStorage: Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module

Tags: react-native, i18next, asyncstorage

I'm using react-i18next to translate a React Native app. It works, but I can't retrieve the user's locale in `AsyncStorage` when launching the app. The error is:

> ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes

The code is:

```js
import i18n, { LanguageDetectorAsyncModule } from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import { Platform, NativeModules } from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import en from "./en.json";
import fr from "./fr.json";

const languages = {
  EN: "en",
  FR: "fr",
};

const resources = {
  en: { translation: en },
  fr: { translation: fr },
};

const detectLocale = async () => {
  const storedLocale = await AsyncStorage.getItem("locale");
  if (storedLocale) {
    return JSON.parse(storedLocale);
  }
  const mobileLocale =
    Platform.OS === "ios"
      ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale ||
        NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0]
      : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;
  if (mobileLocale) {
    return mobileLocale.split("_")[0];
  }
  return languages.EN;
};

const LanguageDetector = {
  type: "languageDetector" as LanguageDetectorAsyncModule["type"],
  async: false,
  init: () => {},
  detect: detectLocale,
  cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};

export default i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: languages.EN,
    keySeparator: ".",
    whitelist: [languages.EN, languages.FR],
    interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
  });
```

So the error comes from the `detectLocale` function, called in `LanguageDetector.detect()`. It's async, I use the `await` keyword. Everything works fine without `AsyncStorage`, so the error must come from here.

I use React Native CLI, no expo, the version is the most recent one to this date: 0.64.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similiar issue.
In order to use async custom language detector, you need to set async to true. Then you will receive callback function on detect().

```
const languageDetector: LanguageDetectorAsyncModule = {
  type: "languageDetector",
  async: true,
  // Since we set async to true, detect has now callback function...
  detect: async (callback: (lang: string) => void) => {
  const language = await AsyncStorage.getItem('language')
    callback(lastSelectedLang);
  },
  init: () => {},
  cacheUserLanguage: (lng: string) =>
    AsyncStorage.setItem('language', lng),
};
```